# dnvm upgrade fails to unpack runtime with RPC_E_SERVERFAULT on CopyHere

Tags: .net, dnx, dnvm

I am trying to install ASP.NET Core for the first time. Installing dnvm with PowerShell works fine, but downloading dnx fail.

When running dnvm upgrade, the process starts out eating a lot of memory (15 GB!) and freezes my computer, the process then fails with the following error message:

```
Determining latest version
Downloading dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1 from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
Invoke-Command : Exception calling "CopyHere" with "2" argument(s): "The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))"
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\dnvm.ps1:1451 char:27
    +             Invoke-Command <<<<  ([ScriptBlock]::Create("dnvm-$cmd $cmdargs"))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-Command], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Searching for CopyHere, 0x80010105 and RPC_E_SERVERFAULT all turns up no relevant tips.

I get the same problem with both `dnvm upgrade` and `dnvm upgrade -unstable`.

Comment: Sure, something eventually goes kaboom when it swallows 15 jiggabytes.  That error code does not help you of course.  This is beta quality, anything can and will go wrong, best to let the project members know if you can't debug it yourself.  But focus on getting your machine healthy first, this quacks heavily like wonky anti-malware, maybe a shell extension.  If it is Avast then get it rid of it asap.

Comment: @HansPassant: Brilliant! It was Symantec anti-virus that did it. I killed everything that I could related to it and everything worked fine! Brings me to an old joke: "What's the difference between 'virus' and 'antivirus'? 4 letters"